# Can we conclude, that $\int f_n d\mu \rightarrow 0$, as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Firstly let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space

I have already shown that:
Let   $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{A})$, that satisfies $f_n (x)\rightarrow 0$, as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for all $x\in X$. Also set $g=\sup_n f_n$. Then;
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int (g-f_n) d\mu = \int g d\mu$$
Question;

My question is can we conclude, that $\int f_n d\mu \rightarrow 0$, as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

No, since for Lebesgue measure on the line and $f_n = \chi_{[n,\infty)}$ we have $g=\chi_{[1,\infty)}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n \, d\mu= \infty \neq 0$ (and of course, as @MaoWao comments, the proof above does not apply since $g$ is not integrable).